# Is there a maximum value to Application Transaction Counter stored in EMV Chip for CVC3 generation? If yes, does this value resets at any point?

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature, smartcard, emv

As an issuer, what extra configurations need to be made to continue receiving ATC values at every transaction without hitting the cap? Is there any benefit to maintain a list of all previous ATCs for valid transactions?

Answer (score 2):

Security controls are usually bound to specific card application specification and its risk management capabilities, so you would need to make the question more specific.

When implemented and reached, ATC limit would normally make the card respond with error to GPO command, so it would not generate any dynamic cryptogram.

ATC is monotonically increasing so you may use this as security feature provided you are aware that transactions may appear in different order than generated (due to offline processing). Any transaction with repeated ATC would probably by suspicious (unless you are implementing single-tap SCA for PSD2, but these are easily distinguished).

Comment: thanks for the reference to sca and psd2. interesting, I need to read more on those

Answer (score 1):

ATC is a two byte field and it gets checked and incremented every time you issue a GPO and hence technically for all transaction. It does not rotate and the maximum number with a two byte ‭is 65535‬.

Acquirer hosts will log all the EMV data to present in clearing, it is optional for issuer host however. Most issuer hosts maintain the last used ATC for the card and sequence number so that it can check for replay authorizations. Any transaction performed with an ATC same or below the last used ATC will then qualify for replay.